# consul balance the traffic cross regions with consul

Tags: amazon-web-services, consul, amazon-eks

At this point, I have found a few well-documented blogs about how to set up service failover to a different datacenter. However, I am yet to find a way to load balance traffic between 2 different datacenters. This may look like an extreme design issue; however, it seems that due to capacity issues on regions, and dc's we need to look for this. [image]

In the image above we are trying to run primary DC in Oregon, while we have reserver capacity for GPU, we can never possibly reserve 100%. At the same time, cloud providers can not guarantee availability for nonreserved instances for GPUs and c5 type instances. 
In this context, we would need to run on multiple regions and transfer traffic to GPU instances running on other regions only when we see capacity crunch in the local region. Not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this using Consul's service mesh, or just service discovery?

Comment: Just service discovery, and being able to load balance across datacenters.

Comment: Hi @Blake C did you get the chance to look into it?

Comment: Consul's service discovery does not support this today. [Prepared Queries](https://www.consul.io/api/query.html) do allow you to configure a failover policy which can return instances from a remote DC when instances in the local DC are unavailable. However, this isn't exactly what you're looking for.

Consul service mesh supports this use case. When you detect high load in one environment, you can traffic splitting to redirect a certain percentage of your traffic to instances in a remote DC. This can be fully automated so that you can dynamically shift traffic as load increases in the 1st DC

Comment: Will this require to run sidecars?

Comment: Yes, traffic splitting with the service mesh requires running sidecars on application hosts.